# dynamic window.location after adding an element dynamic

Tags: javascript, html

I put an A tag on my page , and when the user clicks on it, the page will have a new input field to write in information, like this:

**HTML code**

```
<a href="" class="smallLink" onclick="return ioAddNewContent()">new info</a>
```

I don't want to add hash to the url after clicking "new info" so I make the javascript return null, like this:

**javascript code**

```
    function ioAddNewContent(){
    var bigLi = document.getElementById('ioAddContents');
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var label=document.createElement('label');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    label.setAttribute('class', 'ioAddOneContent');
    label.innerHTML='write one info';
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('class', 'longInput');
    a.setAttribute('href', '');
    a.setAttribute('class', 'smallLink');
    a.setAttribute('onclick', 'return ioAddNewContent()');
    a.innerHTML=' new info';
    p.appendChild(label);
    p.appendChild(input);
    p.appendChild(a);
    bigLi.appendChild(p);
    return false;
}
```

after clicking the "new info" 10 times the user have to scroll down to see the **new input field** , i don't want that , i **want with every click of the "new info" the screen should go to that new input field ,**

i know i can do that by adding A tag with a name = "here " on the html code and then put `window.location("#here")` on the javascript code but i want to do that dynamic

**when user click to add the new input field , the screen should automaticly scroll to that new input field**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.focus()` and `.last()`

```
$('a.smallLink').last().focus();
```

This is part of the jQuery set, not sure if you are using a library.

Comment: i include jQuery , but i don't know how to use it, any way i will put ur code on my js file , but where should i put it ? at the last of my function ? on a new function ?

Comment: After your bigLi.appendChild(p); line, just before you return from the function.  jQuery documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/ and very good.

Comment: u the one man , it woooorks ,really thank you , just a line of code and my problems has be solved :) :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could change scrollTop attribute on scroll container (e.g. body, or your div).

Hope it helps.

Comment: can u give me a short example please

Comment: Sure.

Suppose you have scroll on div with id='scrollContainer'. Then you can do the following


var scrollContainer = document.getElementById("scrollContainer")
scrollContainer.scrollTop=scrollContainer.scrollTop+input.width

Comment: but i don't have scroll , my A tag just surround by LI

Comment: Then I think you have scroll on your body element, and you can change body.scrollTop attribute

Comment: is there anything like , windows.location(MY NEW INPUT FILED ) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don`t get it, could you explain your question?

Comment: i mean if i don't want to dynamic scrol to a specific play of the page i put <a name="here"/> and then make windows.location("#here") on my js , but i asked is there an thingk like this windwos.location(MY NEW FILED INPUT)